# Jquery - Download data in chunks from server and keep appending to a file on client

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, javascript-objects

I have my data residing in the Postgres Server in JSON format. The data is in the hundreds of thousands of rows. I wish to provide a link to the user to download the data in chunks ie. not all the data at once because it chokes up memory on the server. Hence, I have the API that makes the calls to get the limited data in a loop. I wish to write the data to a file on the client in CSV format as soon as the response is received from the server.

Usually, the solutions that I am finding are building the array on the client from the server's response and do not write to the file as soon as the response is recieved, and when the file download is done they are writing that whole array to the file at once. But the problem here is that it starts to consume the memory of the client because you are building that huge data blob on the client now until you write it to the file.

So the approach I want to take is, that as soon as the response is retrieved from the server, I wish to start appending it to the file so that I don't have to hold the data in my client's memory.

I have this code that is doing the normal array to CSV conversion, but it is not appending the data to the same file, instead, it creates several files.

```
const writeDataToFile = (data) => {
    const rows = data.map((obj) => Object.values(obj).join(delimiter));
    const csvContent = rows.join('\n');
    const blob = new Blob([csvContent], { type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;' });
    if (navigator.msSaveBlob) {
      navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
    } else {
      const link = document.createElement('a');
      if (link.download !== undefined) {
        const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        link.setAttribute('href', url);
        link.setAttribute('download', filename);
        link.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
        link.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
        document.body.removeChild(link);
      }
    }
  };
```

Comment: Why is this tagged with jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably want to use the [JS Streams API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API), which let's you break large resources down into smaller chunks for easier processing.

Here's an (untested) example, based on your initial code.

```js
// Prepare the stream for writing
async function prepareStream(filename) {
  const encoder = new TextEncoder();
  const stream = new WritableStream({
    write(chunk) {
      return encoder.encode(chunk);
    }
  });

  const response = new Response(stream);
  const blob = await response.blob();
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.setAttribute('href', url);
  link.setAttribute('download', filename);
  link.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
  link.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
  document.body.removeChild(link);

  return stream.getWriter();
}

// Write data to the stream
async function writeDataToFile(writer, data, delimiter) {
  const rows = data.map((obj) => Object.values(obj).join(delimiter));
  const csvContent = rows.join('\n') + '\n';
  await writer.write(csvContent);
}

// Close the stream when finished
async function closeStream(writer) {
  await writer.close();
}

// Example usage
(async () => {
  const delimiter = ',';
  const filename = 'export.csv';
  const writer = await prepareStream(filename);

  // Replace this loop with your API call loop
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    const data = [
      { id: i * 10 + 1, name: 'John', age: 25 },
      { id: i * 10 + 2, name: 'Jane', age: 24 },
    ];

    await writeDataToFile(writer, data, delimiter);
  }

  await closeStream(writer);
})();
```

Comment: Thanks Lissy93, however the content that gets written into the file is showing as

"[object WritableStream]"

and not the actual content.